# When comparing characters, is ischar(x) && x == 'b' equivalent to strcmp(x, 'b')?

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB, I often use this to check if a variable contains a certain single character:

```
if ischar(x) && x == 'b'
```

to reduce clutter I'm thinking of changing it to this:

```
if strcmp(x, 'b')
```

because if `x` isn't a character or isn't equivalent to `'b'`, the comparison returns false as you would expect. Are these statements equivalent in this case or are there gotchas?

More info: `x == 'b'` isn't enough because this returns true when `x == 98`, but in certain cases (like validating user input), `98` may be invalid input while `b` *is* valid input. Also, the first one fails if `x` isn't a standard data type (if it's an object for example). Take this (stupid) example:

```
x = table();
x == 'b'
```

This throws an error because `eq` isn't defined for tables, but `strcmp(x, 'b')` returns 0 because it appears that `strcmp` also performs a type check. Whether or not this exception handling is desirable probably depends on the circumstances though.

Comment: I don't know much about matlab, but wouldn't comparing `x` to `'b'` be enough? Is it possible to be equal to `'b'` and not be a char?

Comment: @CoreyOgburn Yes. `98 == 'b'` returns true in MATLAB, but for my purposes, this isn't good enough because in one case (as an example), I'm validating user input and `98` would be invalid input.

Comment: `strcmp` is the way to go, as answered by @chappjc. Note that `ischar(x) && x=='b'` will give an error if `x` contains more than one character. If you want to do it that way, use `ischar(x) && length(x)==1 && x=='b'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`strcmp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) is the way to go.  The [`==`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eq.html) operator is element-wise. If `x` is not a single character, then the test returns a `logical` array instead of one:

```
>> x = 'abc';
>> x == 'b'
ans =
     0     1     0
>> x = 'bbb';
>> x == 'b'
ans =
     1     1     1
```

Neither are equal, the second one satisfies the if statement.

Also note that while `==` ([`eq`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eq.html)) is element-wise, [`isequal`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html) tests for object equality. The caveat is that `isequal` does *not consider data type* in the test.  That is:

```
>> isequal('abc',[97 98 99])
ans =
     1
>> strcmp('abc',[97 98 99])
ans =
     0
>> eq('abc',[97 98 99])
ans =
     1     1     1
```

If you care about data type, use `strcmp`, if not, use `isequal`.

Consider also using [`strcmpi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi.html) to ignore case or [`strncmp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strncmp.html) to compare the first `N` elements.

Answer (score 2):

They are not necessarily equivalent if the array dimensions are not equal.

This prints 'true':

```
if 'bbbb' == 'b'
    fprintf('true\n');
end
```

This does not:

```
if strcmp('bbbb', 'b')
    fprintf('true\n');
end
```

Comment: Ah ok, so in this case I definitely want `strcmp` instead because I want to reject situations like `'bbbb'`.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason to consider using strcmp instead of the == operator:

If you use the == operator, 
you will get an error when the strings are of different sizes,
and both are at least two characters long.

Example:

```
>> 'aa'=='bbb'
Error using  == 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

>> strcmp('aa','bbb')
ans = 
0
```